# How to start the Cloud9 debugger with MeanJS

Tags: node.js, cloud9-ide, meanjs

newbie warning...

I followed a good tutorial (from FreeCodeCamp) to setup a new Mean.JS stack in Cloud9.
https://vimeo.com/123488494

The tutorial says to start the application by running the command:

```
npm start
```

Which works just fine...   except that the debugger doesn't attach and I can't use breakpoints, etc.

What magic am I missing?

Comment: Within the package.json file, add `--nocrankshaft --nolazy --debug-brk=15454` right after the `node` command within `start`. Does that enable the debugger for you?

Comment: Mutahhir, Thanks for the reply, but I'm not sure what you are suggesting.  Here's a snip from my package.json   "scripts": {
  "start": "grunt",
  "test": "grunt test",
  "postinstall": "bower install --config.interactive=false"
 },
MeanJS starts up using grunt (also new to me).  The grunt file has this entry...    nodemon: {
   dev: {
    script: 'server.js',
    options: {
     nodeArgs: ['--debug'],
     ext: 'js,html',
     watch: watchFiles.serverViews.concat(watchFiles.serverJS)
    }
   }
  },

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out on my own, sort of (no, it didn't take all 2 days).  Here's the detailed "whats up" for the future newbies to stumble on this...

The tutorial said to start the app with the npm command:

```
npm start
```

For some reason not yet clear to me, npm calls the "start script" that is specified in package.json at the path...   /scripts/start  (and some other stuff... read the manual).

The default install had this in the scripts section:

```
   "scripts": {
      "start": "grunt",
      "test": "grunt test",
      "postinstall": "bower install --config.interactive=false"
   },
```

So...

```
npm start
```

is really just a fancy way of running...

```
grunt
```

Grunt is a "javascript task runner", which looks like it runs the javascript in gruntfile.js - also populated by the default install.

gruntfile.js has this entry:

```
nodemon: {
    dev: {
        script: 'server.js',
        options: {
            nodeArgs: ['--debug'],
            ext: 'js,html',
            watch: watchFiles.serverViews.concat(watchFiles.serverJS)
        }
    }
},
```

At some point, grunt is firing off the node server startup command as evidenced by the output message:

```
[nodemon] starting `node --debug server.js`
```

... But cloud9 is not respecting the --debug request for some reason...  to many fancy indirections or something.

So what I did was create a new cloud9 run configuration (Run (menu) > Run Configurations > New Run Configuration):

```
Name: debug
Command: server   <<<  this just executes server.js
Runner: Node.js
```

Then I can use this to debug.  It does seem to be working ok, but just a few minutes into it at this point.  There does seem to be a bunch of stuff that is skipped by starting the app this way...  but the debugger sure does come in handy.  I'll try to use this just when I want to debug.

I love learning new technologies... just wish it was faster.

b.t.w. if anyone has a better solution or more experienced perspective on this, I'd be happy to mark a good response as the answer!

**ON EDIT 2 hrs after posting**

*Another nice side effect of this alternate run approach is that it takes WAY less memory to run!!!!  I no longer get the warning messages asking me to upgrade my precious cloud 9 free account.*